# Docker development version/snapshot

Tags: maven, docker, versioning, dockerfile, docker-registry

I'm trying to achieve the same mechanism as maven provides for SNAPSHOT versions.
Basically, whenever I have a development on a Dockerfile, I want to be able to create temporary versions in my private registry.

I could create a tag and force push on this tag, but I'd rather keep one version in the registry for a given tag.

If Docker image A depends FROM B (on 1.2.SNAPSHOT for instance), then the latest 1.2.x tag will get pulled.

Is there a special keyword in image version that performs what I'm actually trying to achieve ?

Hope this is clear enough :)

Comment: Not sure if I have right understanding. For example you have tags `1.1.1`, `1.1.2`, `1.1.3` and already have a new major version `1.2` with some following minor versions. Then if you found some problem in version `1.1` then you want to build a new version with tag `1.1.4` (let's call it "patch") and you want that all further major versions (like `1.2.<latest>`) will be affected by this "patch"?

Comment: I can't help but think the right answer here is to push each build twice, once as `1.1.x` and once as a `<snapshot>` named tag. The `1.1.x` will never change but the `<snapshot>` will.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't used them, but it sounds like Maven snapshots are used to indicate a development version.  As a result new versions are always checked for and fetched.

To get similar behavior in docker, I believe you'd need to check for a newer base image on each build.  That's an option in docker build: `--pull`

```
docker build --pull -t myimage .
```

Comment: You're right, snapshot are development verisons. However, they don't always get fetched from remote registry / repository. Version is pulled only when the remote source is newer

Comment: good to know - in my testing `--pull` works the same way - it skips the download if the local version is latest.